# Which device should I set as bootloader for Linux, next to windows10? If my drives are in raid

Tags: linux-mint, grub, bootloader

have 5 hard drives:

2 x 450 GB -> raid0 -> SSDWDR0

2 x 200 GB -> raid1 -> save

1 x 2 TB   -> sdc

SSDWDR0 is partitioned:

800GB -> W10

500MB -> W10 reserve

100GB -> Trying to install Linux mint

1GB   -> encrypt

When I set sda a as bootloader (I assume sda is SSDWDR0), I get the message 'Excecuting grub-install /dev/sda failed. this is a fatal error'

When I set the newly formatted ext4 partition on SSDWD03, windows 10 loads like nothing happened.

I dare not install it on W10 reserve, since I'm not sure of the consequences.
So which partition should I chose to have the ability to boot into both systems?

[device select for bootloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6YMz.png)

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 then Linux Mint or the other way around? Linux Mint uses grub and if you installed Windows 10 after a Linux mint you might have written over the bootloader so now grub doesn't have a configuration to boot from.

Comment: windows10 was first installed, then mint

Comment: Alright so this post I found on a Ubuntu Forum refers to reinstalling grub as it didn't get installed properly. /dev/sda typically is the hard disk that contains the Linux operating system. Unless it is bombing the Linux Mint install altogether. I am trying to get a visual on the issue. - https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u#173371

Comment: What happens when you set SSDWDRO5 as the boat loader? Anything at all. It sounds like a boot loader is installed on SSDWDRO3 but has the Windows MBR on it but doesn't see your Linux Mint install which makes sense. I mean you could see set your boatloader to SSDWDRO3 and then do a bdcedit In Win10 to add Linux Mint to your MBR or resolve your grub issues.

Comment: I'll look into bdcedit, never heard of it but seems logical, since mint is installed already, thank you for response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well based on everything it sounds grub from your Linux Mint install is on SSDWDRO. While your MBR from. Windows is on SSDWDRO3. Either could be your bootloader but it seems your grub might be broken. So in order to have SSDWDRO as your bootloader you will have to fix that. Refer to the following article below:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u

Otherwise you can set SSDWDRO3 as your boatloader. However since Mint was installed after Windows it has no knowledge of your Linux installation. You can use bcdedit to add an entry for your Linux installation. This article shows how you can add an entry using it:

https://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit

There is also a utility called EasyBCD that you can look into if CLI tool sets aren't your thing.